# Will A PCIe Sata Controller help me circumvent AHCI woes?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sata, pci-express

I have re-purposed an old machine to be a home server.

The first thing I did was install Windows 7 to a spare C300 64gb Sata 3 SSD that I had.

I realised after setting up, and updating windows, that AHCI isn't enabled. And I couldn't find anywhere in the BIOS to enable it (I was planning on using the [registry hack](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61869-ahci-enable-windows-7-vista.html)).

The motherboard is a Gigabyte 945GCM-S2L.

My question is... if this board truly does not support AHCI, then can I get around this (whilst making use of SATA3) using a PCIe1 controller [such as this one](https://www.m-ware.de/adapter-und-konverter/adapter-msata/m-ware-pcie-express-x1-msata-sata3-hdd-ssd-controller-id13603/a-13603/)?

Comment: If you cannot set AHCI in the BIOS, stay with IDE. The performance difference is not great. The PCI-e card will probably not change anything.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Also do you know if a PCIe controller AHCI capability/driver is independent of the motherboard?

Comment: It is true that the board does not support it, it uses intel ICH7 for the controller http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_Controller_Hub#ICH7 (also many users confirm that). . .  Chaging the driver (or registry) to run under AHCI mode will only cause the system to crash while driver loading (not boot), because the driver change has to have the hardware support (and switched).   As for an Add-on board , where did you see that it supports it?  Agrees with Whs where there were people running ok with SSD, where you do not have trim and garbage collection occuring.

Comment: @Psycogeek I changed the registry because I thought maybe Enhanced mode was AHCI. Windows hasn't crashed, but no hardware detection was triggered.

Regarding the add-on board, I assumed it would work because it's PCIe and would have Win7 drivers. Am I wrong? Will it be subject to the same motherboard limitations, or will it's drivers run independently? i.e. in AHCI mode.

Comment: I do not know enough, you will have to have a Disk controller (again) on said add-in board that would support these features, then avoid following web  tutorials on turning on AHCI for the MBs controller, because you are not doing that anymore.  Yes Add-on boards usually have thier own driver items, and also can have a Bios that loads.Will also have-to have its own bios to be able to boot via the add-on card.  Vrses say some add-on card that is just to add ports.

Comment: From the card you linked to: `This controller is not bootable.`

Comment: Ugh. The typos on that website: " PCI-Experss ", " systerm files ", " stored in SSD autoly ".

Comment: Maybe this card is better... http://www.amazon.com/Apricorn-Velocity-Performance-Upgrade-VEL-SOLO-X1/dp/B0090IA3AU

Comment: ok so now does your board http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2669&kw=945GCM-S2L#sp support PCI 2.0 specs?  Could be when you get around to all the issues you have and can have when setting-up, an upgrade of the (usually lower priced) mini board would, in the long run be better, Just because the capacitors do not live forever (depending on actual use, and heat, and original quality).

Comment: Here it says it doesn't matter? http://www.trentonsystems.com/applications/pci-express-interface

Comment: It will if the board is not willing to be compatable. :-)

Comment: PCI-e V1 and V2 should be compatible. (Just with lesser speed when the highest shared version is v1). Having said that: Yes, some boards do not follow specs properly. Sometimes it is an issue. I *should* work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will A PCIe Sata Controller help me circumvent AHCI woes?

It might. I does not need to. I should though.

Now a bit more verbose:

AHCI needs to be supported and enabled on the device and its support. This includes the BIOS.  Several older chipsets (ICH7 era) did have AHCI capability but not the necessary support in the BIOS to actually use it.

Using a plug in card with its own chipset and its own drivers can allow you to use AHCI on the SATA ports connected to that new card.  (Obviously if you have an ancient card from the same era then the same problem as with the motherboard may apply. So check before buying).

As to advantages:
AHCI offers things like hot plugging and queuing. The last tend to speed up IO at higher queue depths.  The effect varies per controller, OS and drive, but typically this will not make much difference when reading large files. It can significantly speed up reading many smaller files (e.g. benchmarks at 4K size, QD 16 or higher). The last is very nice for the disk your OS is on, and useless for a data partition.

A second possible advantage would be using a SATA-III controller, which would give you higher speeds. (The ICH7 is not SATA-III).

In this specific case your PCIe lanes come from the North Bridge <sup>*1</sup> which is an Intel 945GC express chipset.  That is an PCI-e v1 setup<sup>*2</sup>. This means you get at most 2.5Gbit/sec per used PCI-e lane.

Since the card you reference is an x1 card it will use at most one lane<sup>*3</sup>. 1 lane pair at max 2.5Gbit/sec is max 2.5Gbit/sec throughput.

Max throughput for SATA 1.5Gb is 1.5Gbit/sec. Which is less and which will not be limited by the PCI-e bus.

Max throughput for SATA 3.0 (sometimes called SATA-II) is 3.0Gbit/sec. This is more and you will not be able to max out a SATA 3.0G / SATA-II device with this card.  It will still work, just not at max SATA 3.0G speeds.

Realistically though max measured speeds for SATA-II / SATA 3.0G are 270MB/sec. And the PCI-e lane limits you to max 312MBytes/sec<sup>*4</sup> throughput.

SATA 6.0G / SATA-III is wasted on such a card.  (It might still be useful on a card with its own cache and bursty behaviour. But then you are well away from cheap plugin cards and into real HW RAID territory. Those cards add a digit after the price tag.)

---

<sup>*1</sup>Source: [The manual for your motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2669&kw=945GCM-S2L#sp).

<sup>*2</sup>source: [Intel datasheets](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/307502.pdf)

<sup>*3</sup>: You can put the card in x1, x4, x8 or even x16 slots (and your motherboard has both x1 and x16). But it will still use at most one lane, even if plugged into the x16 slot.

<sup>*4</sup>

- 2.5       Gbit/sec equals
- 2.5 x 1024Mbit/sec equals
- 2.5x1024/8 MByes/sec, or 312MB/sec

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted to know. It's for the OS, and is Sata 3. So I think I will benefit from a PCIe controller. Now I think it's PCIe 1.0 (not 2.0), and there is a x1 slot and x16 slot (currently GPU, but I can fall back to on board if necessary). What do I have to consider here?

Comment: Edited into the answer since the comments lacked some functionality/formatting.

Comment: I'm a little lost in your new explanation. So you are saying that a card that supports 2.0/1.0 PCIe and AHCI will bring me benefit? Where is the bottle neck in speed exactly? If I read your edit correctly I think you say that with a single lane I'm fine with Sata II but not Sata III. Is that correct? Can I improve this by getting a unit with a greater number of lanes? say x4 or x8?

Basically I want it to be faster than the Sata II port on the motherboard. Otherwise all I'm getting is AHCI and a couple of extra Sata ports.

Comment: Here is a card that is 4x http://www.ebay.com/itm/Asus-U3S6-USB-3-0-True-SATA-Controller-6GB-s-PCI-Express-4-Card-/160949907394?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item25795cafc2

Comment: You have a pipeline: [1:Drive with max speed] [2:Controller on the drive] ---cable---- [3controller on the addin card or on the motherboard] [communication from that controller to the rest of the system (e.g. via PCI-e lanes].  The speed is limited by the weakest link.  In your case the weakest link is between point 3 and 4 where your x1 controller talks slower to the rest of the system than that it can talk to the SSD. 

Feel free to ignore that though. Any speed gains there are likely to be small comapred to the gain from HDD to SSD.